# Decoupling VLC volume and system volume

Tags: fedora, vlc-media-player

I have Fedora 20 + VLC 2.1.4. Whenever I change the volume in VLC, it affects the volume of my system as well.

Is there some setting/config that I can modify to prevent this from happening?

Comment: How do you change volume? Are you using keyboard multimedia keys?

Comment: I'm using the scroll wheel to change volume.

Answer (score 8):

This is due to `PulseAudio` configruation.
As mentioned here http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/User:Feystorm#PulseAudio_per-application_volume_control

> PulseAudio supports per-application volume control, but by default this doesnt do much as you can only control these volumes from the pulseaudio volume control utility. Meaning that in an application like Audacious, when the output device is set to PulseAudio, and the volume control is set to hardware, it will adjust the master volume control, not the per-application volume control.

So, to fix this behavior set `flat-volumes = no` in  `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to enable per-application volume control.